# Compare 2 text cells and show difference in the third cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2007

If cell `A1 = abcd`, cell `B1 = abcdefg`, then what formula to use in order to get the text difference `efg`?

Comment: What would you expect the answer to be if A1 = bcd and B1 = adefg ?

Comment: I expect nothing to happen (tested it of course in advance), because the string isn't present in the other string. @Lee: what would you expect?

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra - I was trying to get the OP to suggest what he was trying to achieve. I don't it's completely clear what he's asking for. After all what does "text difference" mean?

Comment: @Lee, the OP wants to have "efg" aka the difference.

Comment: @JacobJanTuinstra  Hmmm, so the text difference should be all the characters in B1 that are not in A1? So, with A1 = bcd and B1 = adefg this would be aefg? Do you not see the ambiguity?

Comment: @LeeTaylor: I've interpreted it as being a string, not characters. So, in my example A1=bcd, B1=adefg would yield C1=adefg. Can you offer the solution, if they are to be seen as characters?

Answer (score 12):

By using the following formula, you can achieve just that:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(B1,A1,"")
```

Reference: [SUBSTITUTE](https://support.office.com/en-US/article/SUBSTITUTE-function-6434944E-A904-4336-A9B0-1E58DF3BC332)

Comment: so simple... :-) nice! ...but of course not directly extensible to differences in the middle or when you don't know which cell might have the extra "different" characters - thanks for what it's worth though.