# Compare 2 text cells and show or count difference

Tags: microsoft-excel

Let's say we have:
`cell A1 = blabla aaa`
`cell B1 = blabla bbb`

What kind of formulas are to be used in order to get the number of differences between the two texts?
(It should return 3, here, or maybe the text `bbb` if this is easier to do.)

I found this topic ([Compare 2 text cells and show difference in the third cell](https://superuser.com/questions/518214/compare-2-text-cells-and-show-difference-in-the-third-cell)) but that didn't answer to my need as the text of A1 needs to be fully found in the B1, it isn't my case.

Of course, I'll be able to use a VBA solution if there is no solution using only formulas.

Comment: I suggest you use [VBA and the Levenshtein Distance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4243652/935614) for this task

Comment: @nixda, thank you for your suggestion, it seems pretty nice!

Comment: @TakitIsy,, any universal Formula can't finds the difference since pattern may change like Space or Comma as delimiter or even without delimiters !! Better think for VBA .