# Find the part of the string that distinguishes a string in one cell from a string in another cell

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, string

I have two columns with strings and want to know which parts of the string from one column has with the other column. I have checked this solution [Compare 2 text cells and show difference in the third cell | Super User](https://superuser.com/questions/518214/) but it does not work for my problem.

In the screenshot below, I want to the result column to have the string `Elementary` since this is what differentiates `B2` from `A2`. I tried using `=SUBSTITUTE(A2,B2,"")` based on the solution in the link above, but what the formula does is do the opposite by displaying the common strings in both columns:

[image: formula screenshot]

How can I make it display the string difference (`Elementary`) instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How can I make it display the string difference (Elementary) instead?

> Here's a custom function called `WORDDIF` that may do what you want.
>
> To install the custom function...
>
> - Alt+F11 to open the VBA Editor
> - From the VBA menu, select Insert > Module
> - Paste the code below in the VBA Edit window
>
> Back in Excel, put this formula in C1
>
> ```
> =WORDDIF(A1,B1)
> ```
>
> Code:
>
> ```
> Function WORDDIF(rngA As Range, rngB As Range) As String
>
>     Dim WordsA As Variant, WordsB As Variant
>     Dim ndxA As Long, ndxB As Long, strTemp As String
>
>     WordsA = Split(rngA.Text, " ")
>     WordsB = Split(rngB.Text, " ")
>
>     For ndxB = LBound(WordsB) To UBound(WordsB)
>         For ndxA = LBound(WordsA) To UBound(WordsA)
>             If StrComp(WordsA(ndxA), WordsB(ndxB), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
>                 WordsA(ndxA) = vbNullString
>                 Exit For
>             End If
>         Next ndxA
>     Next ndxB
>
>     For ndxA = LBound(WordsA) To UBound(WordsA)
>         If WordsA(ndxA) <> vbNullString Then strTemp = strTemp & WordsA(ndxA) & " "
>     Next ndxA
>
>     WORDDIF = Trim(strTemp)
>
> End Function
> ```

Source https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/486708-compare-two-strings-find-difference.html

Comment: I cannot believe that Excel 2016 does not natively have this extremely useful function. Thank you very much.

Comment: @JAT86 Excel is primary a spreadsheet application not a tool for text management. There are infinite "extremely useful functions" not natively included.